# C# MVC Windows application

Tags: c#

for developing a application in C# windows application which one is better MVC or creating class file for each form

Comment: Not sure if you're asking the right question.

In general, when you use Forms for UI, you will end up with a class for each form. 

If you choose to do MVC with Forms, the Form is how you implemented the "V" (View) -- so its not that you're choosing one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

Right now the suggested direction for a Windows application would be WPF using the MVVM patern (Model, View, View Model). There seems to be a good match between WPF and use of a View Model by way of declarative binding and other nice stuff.

There are articles here: http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/mvvm/ that should point you in the right direction plus stuff on Channel9 and elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WPF, ModeL View Presenter (variation of mvc) is the best choice. In case of Windows Forms MVC is unnatural but still you can emulate it partially with this technology.

Comment: I think in windows application MVC pattern will elaborate the coding

Comment: Yes, indeed. Actually I have an experience with MVP + Windows Forms and it is a bad experience.